# Create list from column-row matches

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with the first row being column headers, and the first column being row labels. I have put `TRUE` in every cell where these match up.

I need to generate a list in a separate sheet for each column, containing only the matching row names where the cells are `TRUE`.

So if `B13`, `B15`, and `C12` in sheet1 are `TRUE`, then sheet2 will show column `B` with `13` and `15` under it, and column `C` with `12` under it. Except using the labels I've input, instead of letters and numbers.

I haven't managed to wrap my head around where to start with this one, so any pointer in the right direction is appreciated.

I've tried creating a defined name for the column headers and row labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't fully understand the layout of your table, but assuming it looks like the following example I tested, this VBA should work.

**Sheet1 table format**

[image]

**Sheet2 output results**

[image]

**VBA**

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
lRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

With ws1

    For j = 2 To lCol
    ws2.Cells(1, j).Value = .Cells(1, j).Value

        For i = 2 To lRow

            If .Cells(i, j).Value = True Then

                ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Value 'This will probably need to be changed to 'i' to represent the row number for your purposes

            End If

        Next i

    Next j

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Take good care of that crystal ball;it's certainly better than mine.

Comment: It was a rental, only one charge in it ;)